# How to get parameter names from a parametrized string?

Tags: python, parameters

What I'd like is:

```
param_str = "I like $thing_I_like and dislike $thing_I_dislike. What does $person_I_like like?"
get_params(param_str)  # -> ("thing_I_like", "thing_I_dislike", "person_I_like")
```

I've looked through `string.Template`, it does only substitution.

Is there a standard library way to do this? Because in case of regex, there would have to be a check if `$smt` is actually a valid Python variable name and so on.

Comment: *"...and so on"*: what exactly?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Template includes the delimiter (`delimiter`) and regex pattern (`idpattern` and possibly `braceidpattern`) as class attributes already.

Comment: @trincot check if the variable actually was an escaped sequence like `$$1000`. I dunno, what else, but I wondered if there is a tool for this already, instead of reinventing the wheel. It doesn't have to be with `$`, `%(varname)s`. Anything goes, in fact.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `s = "I like $thing_I_like and dislike $thing_I_dislike. What does $person_I_like like?"; t = Template(s); re.findall(t.idpattern, s);` will return `['like', 'thing_', '_like', 'and', 'dislike', 'thing_', '_dislike', 'hat', 'does', 'person_', '_like', 'like']`. `braceidpattern` is `None`.

Comment: Right, because they're all the valid `idpattern`s, you're not including the _delimiter_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry, rollback lol

Comment: @jonrsharpe all good. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`string.Template`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Template), or one of its subclasses, stores the compiled regex that will be used to find identifiers to replace as the `pattern` class attribute. Therefore you can do:

```py
>>> from string import Template
>>> s = "I like $thing_I_like and dislike $thing_I_dislike. What does $person_I_like like?"
>>> Template.pattern.findall(s)
[('', 'thing_I_like', '', ''), ('', 'thing_I_dislike', '', ''), ('', 'person_I_like', '', '')]
```

The groups in the result are:

- `escaped` (e.g. `$$` -> `"$"`);
- `named` (e.g. `$identifier` -> `"identifier"`);
- `braced` (e.g. `${noun}ification` -> `"noun"`); or
- `invalid` (*"any other delimiter pattern (usually a single delimiter)"*, e.g. `$` -> `""`).

For your purposes, therefore, you probably want:

```py
>>> [
...     named or braced
...     for escaped, named, braced, invalid in Template.pattern.findall(s)
...     if named or braced
... ]
['thing_I_like', 'thing_I_dislike', 'person_I_like']
```